# Отправить POST без формы Yii2

Tags: php, ajax, yii2, http, post

Добрый вечер! Имею yii2 и некую форму. Форма методом post отправляет данные на контроллер `/results/group/$pageNum`

Если `$pageNum` не пришел - значит он равен 1.

Далее в `actionGroup`я обрабатываю данные и вывожу результат.

Вся проблема в том, что форма - это некий фильтр для поиска. Т.е. результатов может быть и 100, а на странице отображается всегда только 10.

После того, как я вывел результат, к `$pageNum` я прибавляю единицу и вот тут начинается самое интересное.

Мне нужно отправить те же данные, что я получил из POST на ЭТОТ же controller и action, но с новым параметром `$pageNum`.

Как мне это сделать? Как сгенерировать ссылку (или как это правильно назвать) которая отправляла бы эти данные именно через POST на эту же страницу с новом параметром `$pageNum`?

Я вижу следующие решения:

1. Использовать AJAX и AJAXом вытаскивать данные. Но тогда будут костыли:

Ответ для AJAX должен быть в виде JSON (ну или около того), а мой `actionGroup` контроллера `result` генерит верстку. И тогда получается нужен еще один action, который бы генерил JSON для 2 и послед. страниц.

В добавок к этому результаты содержат изображения, сами результаты генерятся на основе ответов ВК и при медленном интернете пользователь тупо не поймет, что все работает, просто нужно ждать. Индикаторы загрузки это тот еще гемор. Как быть?

2. Использовать GET
   Тут не буду долго объяснять, но это мне не подходит.

Я допускаю, что где-то я, возможно, ошибся в архитектуре, но где? Как это сделать?

Comment: это называется пагинация, друг мой!

Comment: @КириллМатасов, извини, но твой ответ бесполезен. У меня модель не связана с бд никак, а данные пуляются методом post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простите, но с каких пор GET подходит для получения данных меньше чем POST? o_O Почитайте про предназначение запросов - POST, GET, PUT, DELETE и прочие. Почитайте про rest. Более того, пагинацию, по нормальному, никто не делает на POST запросах. GET или URL, но никак не POST.

Но если все же очень нужно...

```
<?= Html::a('Text', 
    ['/controller-name/action-name'], [
    'data-method' => 'POST',
    'data-params' => [
        'value1' => 'value 1',
        'value2' => 2,
    ],
]) ?>
```